# Dynamically cell color change in DataGridView

Tags: c#, ms-access, data-binding, datagridview

I am working on a database application. In which some columns are text column and one column is for date. I want to compare Column's date with system date and want to turn cell background color Red when column's date value is less than system date. Below given codes I have tried but not working.

```
private void EMIDGVAdm_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.EMIDGVAdm.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Date_1")
        {
            var EMIDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EMIDGVAdm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Date_1"].Value);
            if (EMIDate <= DateTime.Now)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                //e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? did the debugger go inside if condition?

Comment: Yeah, it went inside if.

Comment: Sir, I tried 1 other first one is                        
private void EMIDGVAdm_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < EMIDGVAdm.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(EMIDGVAdm.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) > System.DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    EMIDGVAdm.Rows[i].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }

Comment: Well. Which one are you using now? and whether it goes inside the condition. I feel e.CellStyle.BackColor should work

Comment: Sir, i am using which is provided with question body.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59b0b9ee-b4c9-4a69-be01-8d015e8030a9/doesnt-change-background-color-of-datagridview?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Sir, e.CellStyle.BackColor is correct but problem is with databindings or something else because this code works well in other project which is not on access DataBase but some entries of Column and Row has made within code for DataGridView.

Comment: Is there an error message? Or cells just don't color?

Comment: I get error message that column name cannot be found. Yes, I adjusted code to use my schema.

Comment: With question body code, it is showing no error message but cell don't color.

Comment: I managed to get your code to work but had to change the line `var EMIDate` to reference columns collection design name which is different from DataPropertyName. Now I get null exception when it hits record with null.

Comment: Instead of var EMI, what did you used and did u look at my edited question

Comment: Yes, I saw the edits. Don't know why procedure works when the same name string is referenced. Instead of `DateReturn` I had to find the gridview columns collection name for that column, not the DataPropertyName. In my project the names are `EffDate` and `effDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.

Comment: Correction, "instead of `Date_1`". However, same idea regardless which procedure you look at.

Comment: Can you post your new code here for better view.

Comment: Perhaps you need to edit question to show code binding to Access, since you suspect that is true source of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Today` if time part is not needed. A `try catch` handles possible null in date field. Have to use gridview columns collection name in the `var EMIDate` line which is probably different from the DataPropertyName. So for the gridview in your working procedure, they are likely the same.

Analyzed OP's project. Seems the code would not read columns out of view so had to widen the DataGridView and panel to display Date_1 column without scrolling. Also, the DataPropertyName does not have underscore. Adjusted design and code works:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Date 1")
        try
        {
            var EMIDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["date1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
            if (EMIDate <= DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
}
```

Found a textbox that appears to be misnamed. Possibly textBox6 should be txtEMI6 for consistency with naming of other controls.

Comment: if (Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[5].Value) < DateTime.Today) This line of code through error object cannot be cast to DB null

Comment: None of my records have null so I didn't get error. Haven't figured out how to handle null exception. So easy in VBA.

Comment: Added a `try catch` to handle null field.

Comment: Also, went back to your code. My version did not work after all.

Comment: Sir, did you try above code with access DB, if yes than attach to me because i still not getting response. You can mail me or send me some link to download it.

Comment: Yes, I use Access database. If absolutely nothing happens, did you remember to put the CellFormattingEventHandler in `public Form1()`? Don't see how providing my files will be helpful. If you want to provide your files, then I will look at. Should probably post in forum that allows attaching files.

Comment: Okay, if it does execute the `If` block then you must have remembered event handler code. So never mind.

Comment: Your file will be helpful for me because i will compare and find my bug or I could use your file with little frontend and backend changes. By 5 pm today i will provide u link as i am not on PC now. If i will not be able to excute.

Comment: Sir, in my VS your code is working perfectly but DataPropertyName would be the same not like you changed above. In my case still unsuccessful, so i am sharing the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kF0RiFzU62GrIkXhpDVB21US8aO6qye5 . Please download it and find the bug and this link consist a zip. The project consist only 2 pages Form1 is mine and Form2 is yours. Please go through and let me know where i left bug. I did not link both form. You can execute from program.cs file.

Comment: Sorry sir for above mistakes and will avoid in future. Sir its working, perfectly but its not working with MetroGrid. Actually my whole project is on metro framework. I will try for it otherwise i will change my project to simple winforms. Again thanks

Comment: I have no idea what MetroGrid is so you are on your own. Is that why I got an 'incompatible' error when I tried to load your project? I actually had to rebuild it using your script copy/pasted via Notepad++. See revised answer. If you feel it resolved issue, please mark as accepted.

Comment: Sir, the project i send you was not on Metro Framework. It was WinForm. I was just asking and going to posted a new question. I request you to go through that one also. It is also a challange for me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'go through that one `also`'? I went through the code in your project.

Comment: Sorry sir, don't take me wrong. My mean was to answer my new question. Which we cant discuss hsre due to policy restriction.

Comment: Does there anyone available to look at my question? What is the fault in question now. Let me know atleast so that i will be able to correct it.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: Above mentioned question. Due to this, I am not able to ask any more question because questioning portal is showing that my question was not received correctly yet. It have -1 remarks and i will be block if ask anymore. Refer above question. What is not correct? If any mistake let me know otherwise upvote my question so I will be able to ask more question. I am in urgent need to ask something.

Comment: I am lost. I have answered this question. I don't know what is 'new' question.

Comment: Ok. Then can u tell me how could i post more question without being blocked.

Comment: I don't really know why you are blocked. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited. Perhaps if you delete or edit some of your poorly written questions, status might change. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve